# Code to determine folder depth "../" in PHP?

Tags: php, directory, templating

Thanks in advance for the help that will be received!

I used to use a code I made when I first started, due to not being able to find a snippet that does what I want. (Maybe to not knowing the terminology) I'm sure there's a more simple way, which is why I'm asking advice.

/*EDIT*/
The pages that will use this template are temporarily hosted in a subdirectory of another website, and using "/" to start at the root of the page isn't an option I want to go with, due to wanting to effortlessly drop the website on a different hosting server and add a domain name to the pages so the path from root (ex. "/temp-dir/site/images/image.jpg") will need updated, whereas, using a previous directory (ex. "../../../images/image.jpg") will work from existing site and new location upon move.
/*endEDIT*/

What I am trying to achieve is applying the proper amount of "../" before the file names in a header template using a method like:

```
<link href="<?php if(isset($pDepth)){ echo $prev; }?>style.css" />
```

Where $prev will equal previous directory code ranging from "../" to "../../../../" depending on the variable $pDepth on each web page. For example:

```
if($pDepth == 3){the output of $prev will equal "../../../"}
```

I seen where the output can change using ++, but you can't add strings can you? I'm thinking something like:

```
if($pDepth == 4){

  $i = 0;

  while($i != $pDepth){

    // help needed here
    // add "../" until $prev = "../../../../"

  }
}
```

I'm still learning to write code, and would appreciate any help. Thanks Again!

Comment: Wouldn't using a virtual root path be easier? For example, if everything is under `/templates/headers/` (e.g. `/templates/headers/my_first_header.php`), just use that as your prefix.

Comment: see the updated paragraph, this site is temporarily hosted as a subfolder of an existing domain, and i want to move it to a hosting server of its own eventually without having to updating the paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$prev = str_repeat('../', $pDepth);
```

Comment: Fantastic, minimal coding and it does what I need! Thanks!

Comment: Did not know about str_repeat, that's kind of a handy function!

Answer (score 1):

```
$pDepth = $pDepth . "../";
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: although if the code is for PHP it would need to be: $pDepth = $pDepth . "../"; or you could simply: $pDepth .= "../";

Comment: Yes, I noticed right after posting :) Guess I am still in C# mode.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate strings in PHP, you use the `.` operator.
Try this:

```
if($pDepth == 4){

  $i = 0;

  while($i != $pDepth){
    $prev .= '../';
    $i++;

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for understanding what i'm looking to do, as clearly stated. i will try this and see if it is what i need!

Comment: This works for what I was looking for. kingcrunch posted a lighter code `$prev = str_repeat('../', $pDepth);` which is also what i was looking for. thanks again as you did understand what i was asking!